# git ps1 bash not loading on Lion

Tags: git, bash, terminal

I have the following in my `.bashrc` file:

```
# Git Bash Completion
source "$HOME/.git_completion"
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE=1

# Prompt
export PS1="\e[0;35m\u@\h\e[m \e[0;34m\w$(__git_ps1):\e[m\r\n"
```

This *should* be displaying the git branch at the end of my prompt... but it's not. If I manually source my `.bash_profile`, it works (my `.bash_profile` loads `.bashrc`). If I quit terminal and startup again, the git branch disappears :(.

What is causing this, and how to I fix it?

Comment: yea... this is awful, but surrounding it with single quotes fixed the problem... I don't understand why though. Could someone explain why single quotes are different than double quotes?

Comment: okay. can you post as an answer (with all that) so I can mark as correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't use git, but I bet the `$(__git_ps1)` portion of the prompt is being evaluated when PS1 is first set (and doesn't return anything). You need to use single quotes, i.e. `PS1='\e....\r\n'`, then the cmd-substitution will be executed each time the prompt is displayed.

Double quotes allow env-vars and other shell features beginning with '$' to be expanded. Single-quotes prevent expansions. That is the purpose of having the two types of quoting.

See tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quoting.html

(I've deleted my comments)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

replace
`$(__git_ps1)`
with :
`$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")`

Answer (score 0):

on some system i have seen that the ~/.profile file is loaded automatically instead of ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile
maybe that is why it works when you source manually your ~/.bash_profile, because your code should be in ~/.profile.

try to rename ~/.bash_profile into ~/.profile